# What does (defn name {:style/indent 2} [param]) mean in clojure

Tags: clojure

I stumbled upon the following syntax in Clojure

```
(defn function-name
{:style/indent 2}
[parameters]
(println "Function Body"))
```

what is the purpose of the `{:style/indent 2}` part and what does it do?

Comment: … and more generally, this attribute map becomes part of the var’s metadata. In this case you would use `(:style/indent (meta #'function-name))` to look it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a hint for the Emacs (CIDER) editor. It means that the editor will automatically indent every invocation of this function handling the first two arguments as special:

```
(function-name arg1 arg2
   arg3)
```

instead of the regular

```
(function-name arg1 arg2
               arg3).
```

It doesn't affect the behaviour of the function in any manner.

See [this](https://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/indent_spec/) for CIDER's indentation specifications.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from [CIDER](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/blob/master/doc/indent_spec.md). It tells CIDER how to indent code that calls `function-name`.